# Suggested setup for angularJS development in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, html5, angularjs

I am starting with AngularJS.  The back end will be Web API (which is new to me as well) and I'd like to use just one IDE, so I'm trying to figure out how to setup a project in Visual Studio 2013 for AngularJS. I'd like to keep it as a separate project, to keep it loosely coupled to the API (or keep the UI decoupled from the Web API).  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this setup. So....

- What project type is best for a pure AngularJS (pure HTML 5) project?
- Is is suggested to use Grunt? Or is MS Build better to handle build tasks? I thinking here linting, minify, concatenating files into a single distribution file, maybe copying to a web server.
- How do you run tests? Is there a plugin to run Jasmin tests? Do you just run Karma separately?
- Are there any good templates for AngularJS? Any that use ngBoilerplate?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: I have a bit of a problem with this being considered too broad. I'm kind of lost concerning this subject and therefore it is extremely hard to be more focused with my question. So, I don't really know how to ask a more specific question at this point. The more I google this, the more confused I get...:(

Comment: I was looking round for a simple answer to the same question.  Perhaps the only way is to completely simplify the question.  I'll add a simpler question and refer to this one.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that this question is too broad.  Get two programmers in the same room and they would a similar question.  In fact, I have the same exact question since we are about to start a web app using the same framework(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the same choices to make.

We decided to :

- make the whole build process *not* depend on visual studio. We chose use tools that are considered mainstream in angular development world. This way getting support by the community is easier.
- use visual studio extensions when available to enhance the experience when possible

How :

- use `grunt` and `karma`. We scaffolded a project using `yeoman angular` and used this as a template to setup our own build process. Ours is almost as-is.
- install the [Web Essentials 2013 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361). The extension uses the same `.jscs` and `.jshintrc` that your `grunt` build uses. We decided to let [Web Essentials 2013 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) handle the `.less` files on save so that `index.html` can refer to `main.css` and no build process is required.
- make sure our visual studio editor settings are aligned with our `.jscs` and `.jshintrc` formatting rules (spacing, line ending, etc).

Also:

- we run `karma watch` (or `grunt watch`) on the command-line for our tests.
- attaching to running karma tests from visual studio works fine, you have to run your tests with IE. But we use the Chrome dev tools more often than not.
- we don't use the jasmine web runner at all. karma has all you need.
- to make things easy our app files are in /static/ inside our WebAPI project. This way you don't need another server to serve your static files.
- you can use [NTVS](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) to debug `grunt` or `karma` or any other tool included in your build process, from Visual Studio.
- integration with our CI (CCNet) was simple, just invoke `grunt ci` where `ci` is a task that does the build and then runs the tests using junit style reporters instead of console type reporters.
- we also made sure that running the build process is optional. The build process bundles stuff in a `dist` folder. We run integrated tests on this folder but at dev-time, we run on raw `js` files (not minified or concatenated). The `yeoman angular` template got us there easily.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. A follow up question: I'm assuming you do use MS Build for the web api part, then run grunt for the ui (in /static/ folder), right?

Comment: The one thing I'm still unclear on is what type of project to use if I wanted to separate the AngularJS UI from the Web API. I understand you put them together, I'm just wondering how to do it if I don't want them together, if you have any ideas on that.

Comment: To your 1st comment: yes. To your 2nd: We put them in the WebAPI project in our dev environnement only. At deployment time they are deployed elsewhere. If you don't pick a *Web* project type then VS features specific to Web projects will not work (Go to Definition in a javascript file for instance).

Comment: Option1: You could use a blank ASP.Net MVC project, delete dependencies and you would will be fine. The only thing is that running this project will compile a `/bin/project.dll` that does nothing.

Comment: Option 2: Create new Node.js project in VS (requires NTVS), it has its own web server (in nodejs) that's going to serve your static files. I tested it and it works.